# How would you call this movement

Tags: definition

When a person is trying to walk in a straight line such as a drunk person, someone walking the slack rope or someone learning to ride a bike/motorcycle  they tent to loose balance and move right and left to keep it, how would you call that
She was _____ while riding the bike. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Losing balance* will communicate what you mean.

> She was losing balance while riding the bike.

The most exact word is probably *wavering*, another that could work is *zigzagging*.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities.  I don't think it would be the same verb with a bike as it would be with walking (possibly on a tightrope).

The first that comes to mind with walking is **tottered**.  Also **teetered**.

A drunk person would tend to have **staggered**.  If they almost fell down (or if they did fall down) they would have **stumbled**.

On a bike they would have **wobbled**.

I'm sure there are other words as well but these are the first that came to mind.